# Trouble with long int on 32bit platform

Tags: php

I'm using MailerLite API.

Calling api with curl in bash I receive user id as

> "id":413076286433501727

But in php

```
$groupsApi = (new \MailerLiteApi\MailerLite($apiKey))->groups();
foreach ($groupsApi->get() as $g) {
    $subscribers = $groupsApi->getSubscribers($g->id);
    foreach($subscribers as $sub) {
        var_dump($sub->id);
        var_dump('413076286433501727');
        $formated1 = sprintf('%d', $sub->id);
        $formated2 = sprintf('%.0f', $sub->id);
        var_dump($formated1);
        var_dump($formated2);
    }
}
```

**PHP Version 7.2.9 Windows NT WINDOWS 6.3 build 9600 (Windows 8.1 Professional Edition) i586**

```
float(4.130762864335E+17)
string(18) "413076286433501727"
string(11) "-1509842432"
string(18) "413076286433501696"
```

**PHP Version 7.0.33 Linux panel.myhosting.name 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 22 10:39:25 EDT 2018 x86_64**

```
int(413076286433501727)
string(18) "413076286433501727"
string(18) "413076286433501727"
string(18) "413076286433501696"
```

What is the way to receive correct value on Win32 platform?

UPD: question was edited after discussion in comments

Comment: Something something, conversion is weird. Try `%d` instead of `%.0f`, since it's an integer and not a float.

Comment: How do you get this from bash???

Comment: @aynber sprintf('%d', $sub->id) returns string(11) "-1509842432"

Comment: @AbraCadaver executing curl [curl -v http://someservice.com/query]

Comment: Which PHP version are you on? Is your PHP a 64bit version?

Comment: where is the php code fragment that get api response and convert it into php object?

Comment: You do not convert from long int but float.

Comment: @Dharman on different hostings I've received different results. I'll post answer in several minutes

Comment: Btw. *'I'm using **some** API.'* is not a useful information.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I've edited the question

Comment: `$sub` is a JSON result of a post request transformed into PHP object. What is `var_dump($sub)`?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone even with JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING I have wrong id because of 32bit platform

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected result for me

```
$groupsApi = (new \MailerLiteApi\MailerLite($apiKey))->groups();
foreach ($groupsApi->get() as $g) {
    $subscribers = $groupsApi->getSubscribers($g->id);
    foreach($subscribers as $sub) {
        var_dump($sub->id);
        var_dump('413076286433501727');
        $formated1 = sprintf('%d', $sub->id);
        $formated2 = sprintf('%.0f', $sub->id);
        var_dump($formated1);
        var_dump($formated2);
    }
}
```

**PHP Version 7.2.9 Windows NT WINDOWS 6.3 build 9600 (Windows 8.1 Professional Edition) i586**

```
float(4.130762864335E+17)
string(18) "413076286433501727"
string(11) "-1509842432"
string(18) "413076286433501696"
```

**PHP Version 7.0.33 Linux panel.myhosting.name 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 22 10:39:25 EDT 2018 x86_64**

```
int(413076286433501727)
string(18) "413076286433501727"
string(18) "413076286433501727"
string(18) "413076286433501696"
```

Thank you @Dharman and thank you everybody

Comment: Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54297270/edit)

Comment: It is overflowing 32bit int on Windows. PHP trying to be smart is converting the value into a float instead of letting it overflow in the first example.